# Various definition of return ratio in a feedback circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, feedback, stability

I am reading about return ratio to analyse stability of a circuit.
However, some of the definitions are confusing.

The first one from the [page](http://www.wow.com/wiki/Asymptotic_gain_model) is defined as below. I understood this and it is not too hard.

[image]

The second definition from the [page](http://kenkundert.com/docs/cd2001-01.pdf) is as below.

I really have no idea about that.

Could anyone explain that?

Does it have anything relate to the first definition above.

[image]

Comment: "I really have no idea about that" - this is unhelpful - clearly you can read English and clearly some of the words and phrases are meaningful to you. State what you do understand and state what part of the text you don't.

Comment: Could you explain what delta symbol mean in a simple circuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a classical control system with negative feedback (negative loop gain) the ratio H=output/input is

**H=Hf/(1+T)**

with Hf=Forward gain and T=-(Loop gain).

1) Hence, T is the product of all transfer functions of the blocks forming the feedback loop - excluding the minus sign at the summing block. Another name of "T" is "**return ratio**". Hence, the "return ratio" is nothing else than the negative loop gain.

2.) More than that, the complete denominator **F=(1+T)** is called "**return difference**".

**Comment:** The above terms ("return ratio" and "return difference") are not in common use today. They were defined by Bode in the 40th of the last century. It is not easy to understand or to "visualize" these definitions because they were invented by H.W. Bode based on transfer functions defined as **input-to-output** ratio. Today, we are using the inverse definition for the transfer function and - as a consequence - the term "loop gain".

Comment: Thank you. With inverse definition of transfer function do you mean the ratio Vin/Vout?

Comment: Yes - that was Bode`s definition. Look at line 3 after Equ. (2). Here Bode speaks about stability and the zeros in the complex frequency plane. Today, we analyze the poles of the transfer function (zeros of the denominator).

Comment: Thanks, could you explain what is delta symbol in Bode's definition? I would like to read more about this to analyse oscillator.

Comment: If you read the original text of the linked document carefully you will find the answer: Delta is the network determinant.

Comment: Yes, I already saw that but it is new to me. I found one in Active Network Analysis by Wai-Kai Chen. I will read more about that.

Comment: Hey - that is really a good book and knowledge source.

Comment: Thanks. I am reading it but the math seems too heavy!